# Database Design: Two tables with same columns but different foreign key

Tags: database-design

I had an original table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSalesOrderPayment]  
(  
    [PaymentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,  
    [SalesOrderID] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [PaymentType] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [AmountPaid] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,  
    [AmountTendered] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,  
    [PaymentDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,  
    [Cashier] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [PaymentStatus] [bit] NOT NULL  
)
```

.. and I designed another table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblReturnOrderPayment]  
(  
    [PaymentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,  
    [ReturnOrderID] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [PaymentType] [tinyint] NOT NULL,  
    [AmountPaid] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,  
    [AmountTendered] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,  
    [PaymentDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,  
    [Cashier] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [PaymentStatus] [bit] NOT NULL  
)
```

.. As you can see it has the same number of columns and types, but they have different foreign keys.  tblSalesOrderPayment has SalesOrderID from tblSalesOrder and tblReturnOrderPayment has ReturnOrderID from tblReturnOrder.

---

1. Once a sales order has already returned, all the payment details should be transferred to the tblReturnOrderPayment, but I need to keep the record from the tblSalesOrderPayment for reference.
2. And once a sales order has returned, future payments will be saved to tblReturnOrderPayment.

What should be the right design for those tables?

Answer (score 1):

At the table design level, you should be asking whether the two tables contain the same type (class) of data or not.  If a row in either table refers to an instance of the same class of entity, then perhaps they should be in the same table, with a flag field to say whether it's returned or not.  If a foreign key does not pertain to a given row, leave it null.

If the two kinds of rows belong to the same class but to different subclasses, then you have a choice of two designs.  These are called "single table inheritance" and "class table inheritance".  You can look up the corresponding tags here in SO, or you gan go ogle articles on the web.